# Animation of KML placemarks and description possible within KML only (Google Earth Tour)?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm dealing with **animating a placemark and its description/label** in a Google Earth Tour. So far I've accomplished animation of a placemark's tooltip ballon via

```xml
<gx:AnimatedUpdate>
    <gx:duration>0.0</gx:duration>
    <Update>
      <targetHref/>
      <Change>
        <Placemark targetId="placemarkpin1">
          <gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>
        </Placemark>
      </Change>
    </Update>
  </gx:AnimatedUpdate>
```

But trying the same with a placemark and its description aka label (as in this tour it would make sense to show the placemark at the end) doesn't seem to work:

```xml
  <gx:AnimatedUpdate>
    <gx:duration>1.0</gx:duration>
    <Update>
      <targetHref></targetHref>
      <Change>
        <IconStyle targetId="pushpin-placemark_normalstate">
          <scale>1.0</scale>
        </IconStyle>
        <LabelStyle targetId="pushpin-placemark_normalstate">
          <scale>1.0</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
      </Change>
    </Update>
  </gx:AnimatedUpdate>
```

`scale` is per definition at beginning at `0.0` 
The both animations are in two separate `gx:AnimatedUpdate` siblings one after the other at the end of the tour.

I can only work in the KML file, there's no possibility to add JS in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unique ids for both the `IconStyle` and `LabelStyle` tags and refer to these in the targetHref for updates.

Note: Multiple changes can appear in a single `<Change>` element (as you have in your original example) or each can be wrapped in its own Change element as children of the `<Update>` element (as shown below).

```
 <Style id="pushpin">
      <IconStyle id="myiconstyle">
        ...
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle id="mylabelstyle">
        ...
      </LabelStyle>
 </Style>

 <gx:AnimatedUpdate>
    <gx:duration>1.0</gx:duration>
    <Update>
      <targetHref></targetHref>
      <Change>
        <IconStyle targetId="myiconstyle">
          <scale>1.0</scale>
        </IconStyle>
      </Change>
      <Change>
        <LabelStyle targetId="mylabelstyle">
          <scale>1.0</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
      </Change>
    </Update>
  </gx:AnimatedUpdate>
```

You can find a complete example with a working tour doing exactly this here:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/tours-in-kml-animating-camera-and.html

Comment: That seems to be a good hint, but it doesn't work for me.
`<gx:AnimatedUpdate>
        <gx:duration>1.0</gx:duration>
        <Update>
          <targetHref/>
          <Change>
            <IconStyle targetId="pushpin-heldenplatz_normal">
              <scale>6.0</scale>
            </IconStyle>
          </Change>
        </Update>
      </gx:AnimatedUpdate>`

isn't working on my side either. As I've written, both animations are in two separate <gx:AnimatedUpdate> siblings elements.

Comment: Your KML still might have syntax errors such that GE will silently ignores syntax it doesn't understand. If you share a more complete full example then debugging the KML would be easier.

Comment: How do you debug syntax errors of KML? Where to look at? I'll share the full KML with you asap, thanks!

Comment: Galados KML validator is good but doesn't support gx: extension tags. I've created a simple command-line XML validator that supports any XML Schema-based XML such as KML and GX namespaces. Can compile from Java source here https://github.com/docjason/XmlValidate

Comment: Use unique ids on both IconStyle and LabelStyle. See updated answer for details.

Comment: You should also get rid of the sentence `You also need a <Change> element around each change action in the <Update>.` as this works in Google Earth v. 7.x with just one `<Change>` around two styles.

Comment: Updated the answer. The spec allows either form.